# Docker restartmanger prevents restart despite restart policy

Tags: docker

I have a docker container that likes to shutdown without restarting, despite having a `restart=unless-stopped` policy set.

Other containers are running on the same host (with similar startup configuration parameters) which I don't have any problems with. The host is a node in a swarm on a somewhat unstable network, and the container is frequent user of the node network (talking to the master node) so I'm not surprised that it would fail regularly, but I expect it to restart itself.

This is due to the restartmanger. The `docker inspect` `State.error` shows a message which clearly came from docker and not my container. The logs show:

```
... time="2019-09-21T02:06:31.969473802Z" level=error msg="restartmanger wait error: Could not attach to network cqr3v2jode1boqh2yofqrh7bx: context deadline exceeded"
```

So it appears that -- occasionally -- when the container gets restarted the network is down and the manger decides stop restarting. The question becomes how to override this behavior.

`docker info`:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 4
  Running: 2
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 2
 Images: 43
 Server Version: 19.03.1
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: active
  NodeID: wgn64s7lx9jvgw36gtlu0dsou
  Is Manager: false
  Node Address: 10.0.0.2
  Manager Addresses:
   10.0.0.1:2377
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc version: 425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.19.66-v7+
 Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: armv7l
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 874.5MiB
 Name: sensors-2
 ID: NTRC:WPLS:GH2P:ZTLM:EDAN:H7HB:HGP6:6G6A:3YVW:T2I7:TVJU:XV3N
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```

Here are the relevant bits from `docker inspect` on the non-restarting container. Note that it has restarted a few times, it exited due to a network error, and the MaximumRetryCount is 0 (which I assume is unlimited). Most recently it wasn't up for long... but my understanding of `unless-stopped` is that docker would continue restarting the container, though it would increase the delay between restarts.

```
[
    {
        "Id": "fa7c59dfa38f25c70d4c1293db27965c2e76af950fa19a2097b4ce63e1af2be4",
        "Created": "2019-06-24T05:25:10.792698029Z",
        "Path": "/srv/bin/weather_collector_server",
        "Args": [
            "/etc/config.ini"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 1,
            "Error": "Could not attach to network cqr3v2jode1boqh2yofqrh7bx: context deadline exceeded",
            "StartedAt": "2019-09-21T03:56:40.911764904Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2019-09-21T03:58:07.234852939Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:ee0e5023f37917f074dd0bf03dca328833eafd117fe69041203533768a196789",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/fa7c59dfa38f25c70d4c1293db27965c2e76af950fa19a2097b4ce63e1af2be4/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/fa7c59dfa38f25c70d4c1293db27965c2e76af950fa19a2097b4ce63e1af2be4/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/fa7c59dfa38f25c70d4c1293db27965c2e76af950fa19a2097b4ce63e1af2be4/hosts",
        "LogPath": "",
        "Name": "/weather_collector_server",
        "RestartCount": 3,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        ...
        "HostConfig": {
           ...
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "unless-stopped",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            ...
        ],

        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "0e901219511bb618d66943a12af1e09d8bbcb78ca4caa0bad88880f21d843c55",
            ...
            "Networks": {
                "hostnet": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "fa7c59dfa38f"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "cqr3v2jode1boqh2yofqrh7bx",
                    "EndpointID": "",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious, but how does it stop itself when it fails to restart? It's not running... docker stop, I presume? :)  Can you rig up a clone and experiment with ways of killing it from docker-enter or otherwise causing the restart failure?

Comment: AFAIK an app within a container can't call `docker stop`. And no, it's python script which exits after an unhandled exception. Actually, I think you helped me half-solve this.

Comment: Hurrah - I'll be interested to hear the solution. I was only being half facetious - I have a container that manages other (Android emulator) containers, so I've given it a REST endpoint to pull updates to those images... and it's own. So now there's another endpoint which makes it kill itself in favour of its own new image. I'm sure that's bad practice, but it's darn useful updating my few dozen hosts.

Comment: Not sure if you saw my edits, but docker gives up on container restarting if it tries to restart the container once and is unable to do so. I filed a bug (https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/787).